# Error using isNumeric() in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am using the IsNumeric() function in visual basic 2012.

my code is this

```
Dim input As String = "123"
    If isNumeric(input) Then
        'number codes
    Else
        'not a number codes
    End If
```

and i'm getting an **error** on the isNumeric(input) part

> isNumeric is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression

i just want to know what is wrong with this, i cant find any documentation that this function has already changed or something.

Comment: none sir and the examples from msdn about information.isnumeric are like what i am using, i still get errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've created a name clash.  You have presumably named your project 'IsNumeric'.  The root namespace for the project is named after the project by default so you now have a root namespace named 'IsNumeric' and that takes precedence over the `IsNumeric` method.

There are a number of options to fix this.  Firstly, you can change the root namespace for the project to something other than 'IsNumeric', which you would do in the project properties.  Alternatively, you can qualify the method name with its namespace, its module or both, i.e. use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsNumeric`, `Information.IsNumeric` or `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric`.

I'd tend to suggest not using IsNumeric anyway.  It can't distinguish between types of numbers and provides no access to the actual numeric value.  If you need to do any of that sort of thing then call the appropriate `TryParse` method instead, e.g.

```
Dim number As Double

If Double.TryParse(someText, number) Then
    'The input was a valid Double and the value is in 'number'.
Else
    'The input was not a valid Double.
End If
```

Note that `IsNumeric` actually calls `Double.TryParse` internally and is the reason it was created in the first place.  That's why calling `IsNumeric` and then something like `CDbl` is bad: you're parsing the same text twice in that case.

Comment: My file is named IsNumeric >_< i created a new project with different name is IsNumeric is working perfectly now... Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange, because IsNumeric is a standard function available in VB.Net. Try to create a new console application:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim str As String = "123"

    If (IsNumeric(str)) Then

    End If
End Sub
```

For me it works.